# PowerBI - Show table items if previous month didn't have value

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I have a table visual that shows items supplied each month to locations along with the total quantity issued.
I'm want to add another column that shows the previous months quantities issued (so I can show month on month changes) but if the item in the current month wasn't issued it's not shown for the previous months. This is further complicated by different items being supplied to different locations i.e. I can't just have a list of everything on my inventory because I'd have a list of hundreds of items rather than those only issued.

I suppose what I need to a way of checking to see what items have been issued to a location over the previous year and generating a list from that but I can't work out a way to do it.

I've tried to create a virtual table that summarises if an item quantity issued has a value but it doesn't seem to filter for location in the visual.
I've also tried to work out a measure without success.

Comment: Update the question above to include a markdown table or even screen grabs to help visualise your ask. In most cases, you will most likely achieve what you are needing with a Measure. Share more details on your data model.

Comment: Thanks Sam, by preparing screen grabs I realised that it was a combination of having a filter set to not show blanks and a measure in the table that gave the current price of items that caused the problem, removing them both now gives me what I needed. Rookie error!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing a filter and a measure that interfered with the visual.